# How to remove a list item from getView function of Adapter class or from instantiateItem function of PagerAdapter class in android programming

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter, android-pageradapter

How to remove the list item from `getView` function of `Adapter` class or from `instantiateItem` function of `PagerAdapter` class in android programming. I am getting Exception in some items in a list. I can catch it but there will be a null item in position. Now I am trying to remove the item from that list. is there any way to remove the item instead of putting null.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

When the ListView asks the Adapter for the item at certain position, it is already too late to modify the item

You can have the following fixes:

1. remove the null items before setting it to adapter, or
2. provide the adapter a copy of the items with null items removed, or
3. return a view with zero height and width in getView() method when the item is null

Comment: I am doing a dynamic image access. There are exception in some files. I am trying to remove the items that fire exception. I tried your third option but got some exception

Comment: Can you try catch and return empty view if exception is caught?

Comment: U mean `return null;`

Comment: Then what about width ?